# ejabberd - what factors limit the number of possible users on a node?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, scaling, ejabberd

With a single ejabberd node, what factors limit the number of possible simultaneous users it can support?

The scenario I'm thinking of is this: Many users on the node, all in the same domain. These users don't communicate with each other, only with users in other domains, through s2s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with ejabberd, the number of sessions per node is generally limited by memory. So things like privacy and roster lists, which get kept in the ejabberd_c2s state, can be big factors. Also locally hosted MUC rooms depending on how many get created, number of participants, history size, etc.